# phpQuery find on div style

Tags: php, phpquery

I can not understand how to search for information in div style.

Example:

```
<div style='font-size:19px;line-height:22px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;'><h1 title='lamborghini aventador 640' style='margin-top:0;'>lamborghini aventador</h1></div>
<div style='color:black;font-size:16px;line-height:13px;margin-top:12px;'>
Article: 640
</div>
```

Comment: I would recommend not using inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is your friend https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/wikis/Manual.wiki

From the phpquery documentation on attributes (https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/wikis/Attributes.wiki)

For a div such as

`<div style='font-size:19px;line-height:22px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;'>`

Calling `$styles = pq('div')->attr('style');`

Variable `$styles` would contain `'font-size:19px;line-height:22px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;'`